# php validate if string is alphabetic including cyrillic, greek or any unicode letter

Tags: php, string, validation, utf

I am trying to validate string is alphabetic including multiple character sets:

```
function is_string($str){
    return preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}\p{Cyrillic}]+$/u", $str) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

but it fails if string contains some other characters of different languages (ç, ë are used in albanian language)

```
is_string('ç');//false
is_string('ë');//false
```

Is there any general function or something which will fix this problem for any character set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\p{L}\p{M}*` matches any letter including diacritics (if any.)

Comment: Great thing, thank you very much :) I tested it a little and look great, can you tell me what \p{L} means?

Comment: This is a fantastic resource on this topic: [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)